# Cant get it to generate random numbers from 5 to 50

Tags: excel

Here i have a piece of code that should generate random numbers from 5 to 50 in the range A2:C24,but for whatever reason it doesnt work also i need it to show and color with different colors the filled cells and the frequency of the element from  cell C3.

```
Sub Random()

Dim Numbers(5 To 50) As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

For k = 5 To 50
   Numbers(k) = k
Next k

Call Shuffle(Numbers)

k = 1

For Each r In Range("A2:C24")
   r.Value = Numbers(k)
   k = k + 1
Next r

End Sub

Sub Shuffle(InOut() As Variant)

Dim HowMany As Long, i As Long, j As Long

Dim tempF As Double, temp As Variant

    Hi = UBound(InOut)
    Low = LBound(InOut)
    ReDim Helper(Low To Hi) As Double
    Randomize

    For i = Low To Hi
        Helper(i) = Rnd
    Next i


    j = (Hi - Low + 1) \ 2
    Do While j > 0
        For i = Low To Hi - j
          If Helper(i) > Helper(i + j) Then
            tempF = Helper(i)
            Helper(i) = Helper(i + j)
            Helper(i + j) = tempF
            temp = InOut(i)
            InOut(i) = InOut(i + j)
            InOut(i + j) = temp
          End If
        Next i
        For i = Hi - j To Low Step -1
          If Helper(i) > Helper(i + j) Then
            tempF = Helper(i)
            Helper(i) = Helper(i + j)
            Helper(i + j) = tempF
            temp = InOut(i)
            InOut(i) = InOut(i + j)
            InOut(i + j) = temp
          End If
        Next i
        j = j \ 2
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: This will error `r.Value = Numbers(k)` because Numbers starts at 5. There are plenty of examples online on how to generate random numbers.

Comment: It takes about 3 minutes to find this site. https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/rnd.php Writing your question took longer.

Comment: Put “=randbetween(5,50) in cell A2, drag across to column C then down to row 24 or use control& enter...

Answer (score 1):

Fairly straightforward route in Excel would be use function `RANDBETWEEN` since you are dealing with range.

```
Public Sub GenerateRandomNumbers()
    '\\ This will generate random numbers...
    With Range("A2:C24")
        .Formula = "=RANDBETWEEN(5,50)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    '\\ Rest of the code for your requirement goes here
    '...
End Sub
```